# how to create a function using python with dataframe to drop NaN values on a dynamic column name?

Tags: python, pandas, qlistwidget

i want to create function to drop NaN values but i need this function to be dynamic means that the end user can select the required column name and not being pre selected column.

Header names:

```
['event_type', 'date', 'event_city','event_mouhafaza', 'number_person', 'groups']
```

## this is the function :

```
def drop_nan(self,df):
        df.dropna(subset = ["number_person"], inplace=True)
```

i need to allow the user to change the **number_person** header's name into  one of the above list item.

the code below show how i display the list of headers  with check-boxes in order to allow the user to check what he want.

system crash and display the below error:

> ```
> self.drop_nan_value.clicked.connect(lambda: self.drop_nan(self.df,self.colname)) AttributeError: 'Widget' object
> ```
>
> has no attribute 'colname'

[image]

## code:

```
import pandas as pd

from PandasModel import PandasModel

import seaborn as sns
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.express as px 
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline.offline import iplot
cf.go_offline()
cf.set_config_file(offline=False, world_readable=True)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent=None)
        self.gridLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout_3.setObjectName("gridLayout_3")
       
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
       
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        
        self.pathLE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.pathLE, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        

        
        self.loadBtn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Select File", self)
        self.loadBtn.clicked.connect(self.loadFile)
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.loadBtn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_3.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 0, 1, 4)

       
        self.displayHeader = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Display header", self)
        self.displayHeader.clicked.connect(lambda: self.print_df_header(self.df))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.displayHeader, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        
        self.displayDF_checked_header = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Print checked item", self)
        self.displayDF_checked_header.clicked.connect(lambda: self.setItems(self.df))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.displayDF_checked_header, 5, 0, 1, 1)

        self.drop_nan_value = QtWidgets.QPushButton("drop  NaN Values", self)
        self.drop_nan_value.clicked.connect(lambda: self.drop_nan(self.df,self.colname))
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.drop_nan_value, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 2, 1, 1)   

        
        self.header_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self)
        self.header_list.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.header_list.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.selectionChanged)
        self.gridLayout_3.addWidget(self.header_list, 1, 2, 1, 1)
   

        self.pandasTv = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pandasTv)

        self.pandasTv.setSortingEnabled(True)


     def loadFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open File", "", "CSV Files (*.csv)");
        self.pathLE.setText(fileName)
        df = pd.read_csv(fileName)
        model = PandasModel(df)
        self.pandasTv.setModel(model)
        self.df = df

     def print_df_header(self,df):
        savelist = list(self.df)
        for item in savelist:
            qitem = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem ( ) 
            qitem.setText ( item ) 
            qitem.setCheckState ( QtCore.Qt.Unchecked ) 
            self.header_list.addItem ( qitem )
        print(savelist)

     def selectionChanged(self):
     checked = []
     for row in range(self.header_list.count()):
        item = self.header_list.item(row)
        if item.checkState():
            checked.append(item)
     print("Checked items: ", ", ".join(i.text() for i in checked))

     def drop_nan(self,df,colname):
        df.dropna(subset = [colname], inplace=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take from user the pandas column name that he/she wants to drop `NAs` from. As in code I can see that is in `self.drop_nan_value`...so just modify your `drop_nan` function as below -

```py
def drop_nan(self):
    self.df = self.df.dropna(subset=[self.drop_nan_value])
```

If user wants to drop `NAs` from multiple columns..then add all those column names in a python list say `drop_col_list` and `drop_nan` function can be modified as -

```py
def drop_nan(self):
    self.df = self.df.dropna(subset=drop_col_list)
```

Comment: i tried your answer  the system crash and display this error`TypeError: drop_nan() missing 1 required positional argument: 'colname'`

if i understand right i need to add the self.colname to the click .connect

`self.drop_nan_value = QtWidgets.QPushButton("drop  NaN Values", self)
        self.drop_nan_value.clicked.connect(lambda: self.drop_nan(self.df))`

Comment: Yes you need to provide the `colname` variable value ..when calling this function. That would be the column name that user wants to drop NA from.

Comment: i add the variable to the function but the system display this error:
` self.drop_nan_value.clicked.connect(lambda: self.drop_nan(self.df,self.colname))
AttributeError: 'Widget' object has no attribute 'colname'`

Comment: i edit my question and add the gui interface with more functions and qlistwidgt and qtablewdget.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Most importantly, you should know how you can get from user the column name that he wants to drop NAs from...and then pass that column name in the function.